# What does this Google Play crash report mean?

Tags: android, game-maker

I am starting game dev. I have been learning Game Maker studio for a while now.

I published my first game to Google Play. After ~1000 downloads I've gotten a few crash reports from a device HTC M9 only:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.jessesopanen.Little_Economist.Gamepad.iCadeDeviceName(Gamepad.java:124)
    at com.jessesopanen.Little_Economist.Gamepad.EnumerateDevices(Gamepad.java:332)
    at com.jessesopanen.Little_Economist.RunnerActivity.doSetup(RunnerActivity.java:541)
    at com.jessesopanen.Little_Economist.DemoRenderer$2.run(DemoRenderer.java:574)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

What's wrong with my game's code or is the problem with HTC M9? I have tested my game with various devices and it works fine.

I don't understand what that crash report means if someone could help me out?

Comment: Could you share the code where it crashes? This would be around Gamepad.java, line 124. There's some nullpointer there.

Comment: This is expected, There are tons of android devices out there and it's impossible to test in each device. These crashes are device specific and sometimes you need real device to catch these kind of crashes. 
Also, Is GamePad.java inside Game Maker Studio SDK? . If so, please check their support forum

Comment: How do I find the part of the code where it crashes? I have the code in Game Maker Studio, it's separated in small parts. Also it does not crash for me when I test it.

Comment: Is there used YYC?

Comment: `java.lang.String.contains` - possible, you trying to do something with string (for example, `string_pos()`, etc) but string is not defined (for example, undefined variable, or undefined value from `ds_map`)

Comment: It's without YYC. Should I use YYC?

Answer (score 0):

this report is just here to tell you that someone of your users have a problem with your app and the report give you the stack trace of the problem

Your problem seems come to a java null pointer exception at line 124 this is a very generic error so read your code test it again and good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to locate where's the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

at com.jessesopanen.Little_Economist.Gamepad.iCadeDeviceName(Gamepad.java:124)

===> begin by testing

```
if(myObject != is_undefined)
{

    //your code

}
```